# How to put widget on positiion of draggable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to set position of picture with Positioned - postioned has properties: top, bottom, left, right
I want to choose position based on where player drags this picture. But widget draggable has properties offset.x and offset.y

After dragging I got x and y from draggable and when i set top = x and left = y , those 2 positions are completely different. Why?

UPDATE: top = y , left = x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `delta` value provided during `onDragUpdate`

Checkout the full example here: https://dartpad.dev/6943a8e1a9ae2a0539edfa7884225372?

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  double top = 0;
  double left = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final child = Material(
      child: Container(
        height: 100.0,
        width: 100.0,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: const Center(
          child: Text('Draggable'),
        ),
      ),
    );
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          top: top,
          left: left,
          child: Draggable<int>(
            data: 10,
            onDragUpdate: (details) {
              top = top + details.delta.dy;
              left = left + details.delta.dx;
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: child,
            feedback: child,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, do you maybe know how can I pass position (top and left) to data? Instead of 10

Comment: Not sure how that's relevant to this question, but you can store the data in a Offset 

```dart

  Offset data = Offset(0, 0);

.....
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
.....
 Positioned(
          top: data.dy,
          left: data.dx,
          child: Draggable<Offset>(
            data: data,
            onDragUpdate: (details) {
              data = Offset(data.dx + details.delta.dx,data.dy + details.delta.dy)
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: child,
            feedback: child,
          ),
        ), 

```